# C++, repeat an input for a function multiple times

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to create an input, which is than repeated N times as a parameter for the function?

An example:

```
#include <range/v3/view/indices.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/cartesian_product.hpp>

template<std::size_t length, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto tensor_cartesian_product(){

    const auto cart_input1 = ranges::view::indices(length); //create input

    return ranges::view::cartesian_product(cart_input1, cart_input1, ... /* N times cart_input1 */);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [pack expansion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack#Pack_expansion):

```
template<std::size_t length, std::size_t... is>
constexpr auto tensor_cartesian_product(std::index_sequence<is...>) {
    const auto cart_input = ranges::view::indices(length);
    return ranges::view::cartesian_product((is, cart_input)...);
}

template<std::size_t length, std::size_t N>
constexpr auto tensor_cartesian_product() {
    return tensor_cartesian_product<length>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

The trick here is to harness the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator):

> The comma operator expressions have the form: `E1 , E2`.
>
> In a comma expression `E1, E2`, the expression `E1` is evaluated, its result is discarded ... . The type, value, and value category of the result of the comma expression are exactly the type, value, and value category of the second operand, `E2`. ...

The pack `(is, cart_input)...` will be expanded into `(0, cart_input), (1, cart_input), ..., (N - 1, cart_input)`, and the result of evaluation of each of `N` terms will be `cart_input`.

Comment: thank you a lot! I am still new to template programming and often i don't know terms like `pack expansion` etc!

Comment: @M.Mac, the idea is expand `N` into `0, 1, ... N-1`. The canonical way to do it is to use `std::make_index_sequence<N>{}` and a helper function that takes `std::index_sequence<is...>` with a pack of indices `is...`.